# Will Pokémon Go Plus device read speed?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am planning to buy a Pokemon Go Plus device. All I want to know is if I drive with the Pokémon Go Plus device paired with my Pokemon go app on my mobile, will I be able to hatch a 2/5/10 km egg if I drive for 2/5/10 km respectively? Regardless of the speed I am driving? Or it just reads distance only if I drive slow or below 20 miles/hr speed? Same as that of the phone app speed reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the report [here](http://heavy.com/games/2016/09/pokemon-go-plus-device-features-does-will-be-able-to-track-distance-traveled-egg-hatch-buddy-app-running-in-background-foreground/), it looks like the Pokemon Go Plus accessory will track walking distance the same as if you had the app open (but you don't have to have it open).

> Pretty much all of Pokemon Go Plus’ other functions will work with the app running in the background, too. That means that you can finally lock your screen, tuck your phone away in your pocket and forget about the app for a while, using the Plus device to play and to track your movement.

[Here](http://www.macworld.com/article/3123689/ios/pokmon-go-plus-improves-the-grind-but-it-can-be-obnoxious.html) is another article that confirms this behavior:

> Also, I’m logging a lot more distance than I usually do when playing on the phone. Where I might turn off the phone here and there and potentially forget to turn it back on, the Plus band remains on for a full hour or until manually shut off sooner. I’m hatching eggs faster than I ever have, and earning quite a bit of bonus candy via the recently-added buddy system, which gives you a free evolution candy for your Pokémon of choice once you notch a certain distance.